# Locating object in array by id and changing its values based on variable parameters: Why does my code work?

Tags: javascript

The problem isn't the code, it's that I don't understand why what I have works, although it does what I need it to do. I'm building an app that keeps track of jobs. The jobs, each an object, are stored in an array in a JSON file. I'm adding the functionality to edit a job's key/value pairs in the JSON file.

Anyway, my function editJob takes in an object as an argument that has an id and a variable amount of other properties. The goal is then to locate the job in JSON that matches the id, then update that job's properties based only on the editItems object.The code below allows for that. I just don't understand the line below the Object.keys code. Why would I not compare the located job's keys to the editItems keys?

I don't know why it works and am worried it will break at some point because it's not properly coded.

```
function editJob (editItems) {
        // editItems is an object like this: ex. { id: 3, customer: 'Artemis', source: 'Google', description: 'Fixed toilet' }
        return this.jobs.map(job => {
            let editedJobs = Object.assign({}, job);
            if (editedJobs.id === editItems.id) {
                Object.keys(editItems).forEach(k => {
                    if (editedJobs[k] === job[k]) { // WHY DOES THIS WORK. why job[k] and not editItems[k]???
                        editedJobs[k] = editItems[k];
                    }
                });
            }
            return editedJobs;
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't get the point of that check at all, actually. `editedJobs` is a (shallow) copy of `job`. What's the point in comparing them? I personally don't see a case where `editedJobs[k] === job[k]` wouldn't be `true`.

Comment: That isn't working the way you think it is. `editedJobs[k] === job[k]` will always be true unless you have duplicate keys in the editItems. But that isn't possible because JS objects can't have duplicate keys. So `if (editedJobs[k] === job[k])` is just always true. It's redundant code that can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just did `editedJobs = Object.assign({}, job)`, the expression `editedJobs[k] === job[k]` will be `true` for every `k`. You can just omit it. You would achieve the same thing by

```
function editJob (editItems) {
    return this.jobs.map(job => {
        return job.id === editItems.id
          ? Object.assign({}, job, editItems)
          : job;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's so much more efficient. I guess I didn't know what the assign method could do. So if the ids match, it returns a new object that is a copy of job and...What exactly is the editItems argument doing?

Comment: The same as with `job`. The `Object.assign` call copies all properties from them over to the `{}` object and then returns that.

Comment: So say: let job = {name: Dave, age: 21} and let arg2 = {age: 50}. A copy of job is created then when arg2 is copied over, the age value is replaced? I'm going to go improve my javascript right after this, but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)